# what should be last few sentences requesting an editor to publish your article?

Tags: word-choice

i request you to publish my article.
or
would you kindly publish my article to your esteemed daily.
or
it will be good if you publish my article. 
 ( suggestions please, this is for my examination to ' letter to the editor' section)

Comment: I like your iniative in asking for help in writing well. However, this site is for advanced users of the English language. Also, StackExchange sites do not answer questions such as this, because the focus here is different. Please approach your teacher or elders. Best of Luck.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman When you attempt to write a "Leave Letter," you are not going on leave, it's an exercise in composition.

Comment: maybe [writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) SE ? (I can't flag as such though)

Answer (score 1):

**Format for a letter to the editor:**

The Editor

[Name of publication]

[Address]

Enclosed is a letter responding to your article [headline] published [date of publication].

I am [one line on who you are—e.g., a student at ___ in the 10th standard].

Thank you for your consideration.

[Your Name]

[Your contact information]

Comment: thank you very much sir.

Comment: Writing advice is OT.

Comment: @Kris I agree. I was tempted to summarize the essential content of such a letter.